# Adding a path to the .bashrc file?

Tags: bash, path, edit, fedora

At the moment I am trying to add a path for ns-2 to my .bashrc file, I have installed the ns-allinone-2.34 but the command ns gives the result: command not found when entered into the shell.

Here is what my .bashrc file currently looks like, I edited it using gedit:

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
. /etc/bashrc
fi


# User specific aliases and functions
export PATH=/home/michael/ns-allinone-2.34/bin/ns:/home/michael/ns-allinone-2.34/bin/nam:$PATH
```

Can someone please explain why this isn't working or what a possible solution may be? I am using fedora 17.

Comment: Have you started a new shell that reloaded the .rc file?

Comment: Is this the binary or the directory : /home/michael/ns-allinone-2.34/bin/ns ? It needs to be the *directory* containing the binary

Comment: AH that fixed it I was using the binary not the directory, I deleted the ns and nam off the end and it is now working!

Comment: Good. I've added an appropriate answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `PATH` should contain the *directory* for the binaries, not the binaries themselves.

For example, in the above:

```
export PATH=/home/michael/ns-allinone-2.34/bin/ns:..
```

should actually be:

```
export PATH=/home/michael/ns-allinone-2.34/bin:...
```

Comment: I did down voted this answer by mistake.. not sure how to revert it.. help me please :)

Comment: Just press the same arrow button again, I think.

Comment: Nope.. It says "Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edtied"

Comment: @Maystro your downvote is justified. This could potentially erase all previous PATH. See the second answer below

Comment: @BinuJasim -  Can you please explain how *amending* a PATH variable to the correct directory and removing the erroneous reference to the binary does not work ?

Comment: @Brian I accidentally deleted all my previously set PATH by executing your command. export PATH=$PATH:/home/michael/ns-allinone-2.34/bin/
will keep the previous PATH. But technically you answered the question correctly.

Comment: You understand the above says 'for example'?

Answer (score 47):

Also if you export path like this, you want to keep old PATH as well, therefore include it as well.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/michael/ns-allinone-2.34/bin/
```

Comment: He did, it's at the end, just as it should be.

Comment: Oh, you are right, I didn't scroll there and expected original PATH to be in the beginning...

Comment: what's the exact difference between this answer and the accepted one? I mean, what happens if "$PATH:" is not added before bin's path?

Comment: @Todea the path gets searched in the order given. So if you put the existing path at the end, any same-named executables will be called instead of the normal ones. This is not usually what you want, and becomes a security hole if the folder has weaker perms than the system command folders: someone can get you to run an arbitrary command just by creating a file in there called "ls". But then, we shouldn't be running exes from world-writable folders anyway :) So, it's handy when you want to override the default system commands, but aliases won't cut it.