# How can I modify my .bash_profile file so I can run my python scripts w/o typing the path to the file?

Tags: python, osx-lion, epd-python

I am new with  OSX and getting familiar with file structures in this environment. My .bash_profile file looks like this:

```
# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

My scripts are in several directories, for example:

```
/Users/LMS/Documents/pydata-book
/Users/LMS/Documents/python_scripts
```

What I would like to do is open my terminal, type the name of the script (for example myscript.py), and be executed, just like one would do by specifying an association of *.py files with Python, in a windows environment.

Anybody out there could help me accomplish this with a mac?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a path to the .bashrc file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631173/adding-a-path-to-the-bashrc-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting this in your .bash_profile instead:

```
# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/Users/LMS/Documents/pydata-book:/Users/LMS/Documents/python_scripts:${PATH}"

export PATH
```

Basically, you put the directories that contain the executable files you want, separated by ':'

Comment: Thank you. I did what you indicated and when I try to run my script from terminal by typing myscript.py, I get this -bash: /Users/LMS/Documents/pydata-book/myscript.py: Permission denied

Comment: I think you need to make the scripts executable, go to the directories with the scripts and do `chmod +x *.py`