# Making gfortran version 11 as default

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, gfortran

My code runs fine with the command

```
   gfortran-11 Hello.f90 -o Hello
```

but if I check the version of the gfortran, it shows 9.3.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.

So my concern is how to make it default or do I have to type gfortran-11 every time I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to [create a symlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951742/how-can-i-symlink-a-file-in-linux/1951752#1951752) to `gfortran-11` called `gfortran`, and to [add this symlink to your `PATH`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631173/adding-a-path-to-the-bashrc-file) with higher priority than the original `gfortran`.

This could be acheived by e.g. running

```
mkdir ~/.bin
ln -s [path_to_gfortran-11] ~/.bin/gfortran
```

and then adding

```
export PATH=~/.bin:$PATH
```

to your `.bashrc` or equivalent.

Comment: Your answer sounds similar to this link which i have previously followed but could not understand the last step like you said about exporting to .bashrc. https://camb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fortran_compilers.html#:~:text=Check%20the%20version%20using%20%E2%80%9Cgfortran%20%E2%80%93version%E2%80%9D.&text=To%20install%20from%20the%20standard,sudo%20apt%2Dget%20install%20gfortran%E2%80%9D

Comment: So my home directory has this folder   gfortran-symlinks. So which command i should put in the terminal for exporting to .bashrc?

Comment: Just use any text editor and put the export command into the `.bashrc` file. You could use echo, but I suggest just doing it manually, it is safer for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a system administration question. Since it tangentially deals with a compiler, it might be on-topic.

There are various ways how concurrent versions are treated in various operating systems. If you use Linux, you can use

```
alias gfortran=gfortran-11
```

You can put this into your `~/.bashrc` or some equivalent, if you use one (e.g., the `~/.bash_aliases` file - see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414/how-to-create-a-permanent-alias).

---

For tools like Make you can normally set

```
export FC=gfortran-11
```

or

```
FC=gfortran-11 ./make
```

or some other variable name that your Makefile happens to use. I use this routinely with SCons.

---

Another good option is the `update-alternatives` system. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/how-to-choose-the-default-gcc-and-g-version

If you configure (install) the appropriate options according to the instructions (change `g++` to `gfortran`), you will be able to switch between the versions using

```
 sudo update-alternatives --config gfortran
```